# Change 3 rows which have the smallest value among all values in R

Tags: r, database, variables, var

I have a data that looks like this

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | f |
| 14 | f |
| 1 | f |
| 7 | f |

What I want is to change the `y` value of  3 individuals with the lowest `x` value from `f` to `t` so my data would look like this:

```
|  x  |  y  |
|:---:|:---:|
|  3  |  t  |
|  14 |  f  |
|  1  |  t  |
|  7  |  t  |
```

Kind regards

Comment: What do you want to do with ties, ie let's say the 2nd row had 7 instead of 14. Are all four individuals in the lowest 3?

Comment: No the last 7 must be an f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this as a one-liner in base R. Use `rank` to get the order each entry takes, find which rank is below 4, then use `ifelse` to select 't' or 'f' based on this.

```r
within(df, y <- ifelse(rank(x) < 4, "t", "f"))
#>    x y
#> 1  3 t
#> 2 14 f
#> 3  1 t
#> 4  7 t
```

---

**Data taken from question**

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 14, 1, 7), y = "f")
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    x = c(3L, 14L, 1L, 7L),
    y = c("f", "f", "f", "f")
)


df %>% 
  mutate(
    y = case_when(
      x == sort(x)[1] ~ "t",
      x == sort(x)[2] ~ "t",
      x == sort(x)[3] ~ "t",
      TRUE ~ "f"
    )
  )
#>    x y
#> 1  3 t
#> 2 14 f
#> 3  1 t
#> 4  7 t
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just arrange the dataframe in ascending order of x, then edit the y value for the first three rows.

```
data <- data[order(x),]

for (i in 1:3) {

data$x[i] <- 't'

}
```